# COM dll without DllRegisterServer, etc

Tags: c++, dll, com

I have a COM dll that exports a custom factory function, `CreateX()`.  Much like D3D11, objects from this dll are not instantiated via `CoCreateInstance()`, and there are no class factories or CLSIDs - only IIDs.  I've removed all mention of the server functions from the ATL project, which builds without problems.  I also linked the dll to a test application, and everything works as expected.

Is there a downside to excluding `DllRegisterServer()` (and the like) in this situation that I am not aware of?

Comment: The only downside is that everyplace you need an interface, you need access to an existing pointer or to `CreateX`. There are times where this may introduce direct linking that you didn't want.

Comment: @MarkRansom Based on what it does, I don't see any situation where my lib wouldn't be linked at compile time, so I guess that's not much of an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no apparent downside. It's a popular misconception that all what is COM related has to be in the Windows registry. On the fundamental level COM is just a convention of binary interoperability. Services available through the registry are not necessary.

Comment: COM has many layers, and *most* of those layers require something in the registry. As you say though, there's a fundamental layer that doesn't.

Comment: DirectX works fine without all these layers. You need registry for some additional sugar. For example automatic proxy creation for calls between incompatible apartments. Especially it is helpful if you use this abomination called IDispatch and type libraries. Or if use some higher level services: OLE, Automation, ActiveX, DCOM, etc. COM per se works fine without registry.